# Change background in commandline

Tags: windows, batch-file, background, refresh

I'm making a script which change your background automaticly, 
I do a php script which download the background, but the background doesn't change every time, sometime it work sometime no.
here's the .bat file :

```
php c:\autoback\getbackground.php
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /d "C:\autoback\background.jpg" /F
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Comment: is the script always executed with elevated admin permissions? Registry edits need to be ran as administrator.

Comment: I try launch as root but it's not more efficient